# How to use revieced message from client as file path in server side in C?

Tags: c, web-services, server, client, recv

I am trying to write a server app in C that gets file path from client and sends the file content back to the client. When i receive the client message and try to use as file path, file becomes NULL and it can not be read.

```
char server_reply[2000];
if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
       break;
    }

FILE *fp = fopen(server_reply,"rb");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File open error");
        return 1;
    }
```

I test my code getting file path via scanf and it works.

```
char path[2000];
printf("Enter path : ");
scanf("%s" , path);

FILE *fp = fopen(path,"rb");

if(fp==NULL)
   {
      printf("File open error");
      return 1;
   }
```

i couldn't figure out what is the difference between server_reply and path. The definitions of two variables both char array. I will appreciate if i can get any clue about it, thanks.

Comment: You're probably missing the NUL terminator. You need to get the count from `recv`, and use that to add the NUL. Also, if you're using TCP, `recv` may not get the whole message in a single call. So you need some way to know when the whole message has been received, e.g. send the length first, or send the NUL as part of the message.

Comment: recv() returns a value.  You must handle that value correctly and completely.  Essentially, what @user3386109 says above.

Comment: 'The definitions of two variables both char array' yes, but not null-terminated!  Nearly all C network code posted here has this same problem of being unable to handle C-syle null-terminated char arrays correctly:((

Comment: Try to print to `server_reply` and check if it is a valid path

Comment: i print both path and server_reply they are the same and correct path

Comment: If the are the same, they would behave the same.  They don't behave the same, so they are not the same.  Doesn't matter what you see when you print stuff, only the char values between the start of the array and the first nul char matter to the file open call.  The recv() call loads some number of bytes between 1 and 2000 into your 'server_reply' array and returns the exact number loaded, irrespective of whether those bytes can be printed or end in a null.  YOU have to ensure that the TCP octet/byte stream gets parsed into a valid path specification with its null terminator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i focused on solving null-terminated char array. I am using telnet as client, is it possible to send non null-terminated string or do i have to handle it after receiving it?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give following recommendations.

1) make sure you receive absolute path.

2)From client make sure you send a null terminated string.

3) Try to use udp protocol, to get complete information in one shot/ or use your own protocol over tcp(say you encode string length and type(tlv encoding))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file `server_reply` exists first. `fopen()` will return NULL if the pointed file path does not exist. It's a simple way to check if the file exists:

```
FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fptr != NULL)
{
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("File exists\n");
} else {
    printf("File doesnt exist\n");
}
```